# a div with height:1px appears very thicker in internet explorer 6. How to reduce it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

This is my css properties:

```
.line-separator {
height: 1px;
background: #d2d2d2;
border-bottom: 0px solid WindowFrame;
color: #d2d2d2;
width: 984px;
    }
```

this is my DIV: (i use one more like this for the bottom one.)

```
<div class="line-separator" style="margin-left: 3px;">
</div>
```

**IE 7 : This is the required look**

[image: IE 7 : This is the required look .]

**IE 6 : It appears very thick. It should not be the case.**
[image: IE 6 : It appears very thick. It should not be the case.]

Please avoid comments like dont use ie6 or move on etc., I am aware its going extinct. I have a requirement in ie6. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `line-height: 1px` or `overflow: hidden`. That will do the trick.

Comment: I don't think `overflow: none` is recognized by any browser.

Comment: Before adding extra CSS, maybe try not leaving any space between your opening and closing tag : `<div class="line-separator"></div>`

Comment: @BoltClock you're right. I wanted to say `overflow: hidden` but I'm a little distraught.